# Can't associate an Elastic IP on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just create a new EC2 instance on Amazon, with default options, and there is no way to associate an Elastic IP with this instance. The options are not available, and I haven't reach my limit.

AWS added automatically an public ip, but I am afraid that this is not flexible as an Elastic IP (I will install Nginx on this instance).

Anyone knows what networking configuration I need to change to AWS allow me set up Elastic IPs?

[image]

Comment: Try going into the Elastic IP interface and allocating a new IP, and then associating it with the instance from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the availability zone it seems your Instance is in a VPC so when you are allocating a new Elastic IP be sure you are allocating the IP address for a VPC as classic Elastic IP cannot be attached to a EC2 instance in a VPC. Once you allocate Elastic IP you will be able to associate that elastic IP using your method.

Check this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Elastic IP addresses are not assigned to EC2 instances on the main EC2 instances list page (as you show in your screenshot).

Instead, go to the "Elastic IPs" page (on the left sidebar of the EC2 Management Console, closer to the bottom). On that page, you will then:

1. Click the "Allocate New Address" to allocate a new Elastic IP address into your AWS account.
2. Choose "Associate Address" from the "Actions" menu to assign that Elastic IP address to your EC2 instance.

When you are done with the Elastic IP address (meaning, you don't need to use it anymore for your EC2 instance), then "Release" the address so it is no longer used by your AWS account. This way, you avoid being charged for keeping an unused Elastic IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my problem was that my instance was on a VPC and the Elastic IPs not.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Addresses:sort=publicIp) and check if are able to attach an IP to this instance.
U will need to Allocate New Address to obtain new IP and then Assiciate.